# streaming audio and video independently as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stream

I have this 2 functions. And as you can see the first one is streaming a video (witch is looping ) and the second one is streaming an audio ( witch si looping too ). So I need when the video is playing the audio to starts running to and to be looped independently because the length of my audio is bigger than the length of the video. Any ideas how can i manage to do that. Use code please.

```
function NCListener(e:NetStatusEvent){

    if (e.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop") {

        ns.play("http://media.easyads.bg/ads/display_ads_richmedia/video/avon/maria_ilieva/video_2.flv");
        shaker(null);
        }
    };


var sound:Sound = new Sound();
var soundChannel:SoundChannel= new SoundChannel();

sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoadComplete  );

function onSoundLoadComplete(e:Event):void{
    sound.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoadComplete);
    soundChannel = sound.play(0, 9999);
    soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundChannelSoundComplete);
}

function onSoundChannelSoundComplete(e:Event):void{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundChannelSoundComplete);
    soundChannel = sound.play(0, 9999);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need the
`soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundChannelSoundComplete);`

It triggers when the sound has finished running, but since it's looping, there's no need to play it again.

First of all, you need to move the line

```
soundChannel = sound.play(0, 9999);
```

And place it right after your `ns.play`. So the sound will start as soon as your video start.
Then, to prevent it looping again when the video start, just check if soundChannel exists :

```
if (soundChannel == null)
    soundChannel = sound.play(0, 9999);
```

Please notice that's there is **no way** to keep your sound in sync with your video afterwards, it depends completely on flashplayer will.

Comment: Yes I know that. But if I put it like you said when the video loops it's going to play again the sound over the first one (because it's not finished yet )  and it's getting really messy !

Comment: That's why I need  both to be played at the same time but to be looped independently.

Comment: It's not working. when the video loops it plays again the audio over the same audio.

Comment: Make sure your soundChannel variable is declared only once, at class level for instance and remove `
var soundChannel:SoundChannel= new SoundChannel();`